# Which ubuntu derivatives plan to support xorg in the future?

Tags: xorg, mir, derivatives

As far as I know ubuntu plans to replace xorg with mir in the future. WM's who need xorg will run on an intermediate layer called xmir instead. In which version will ubuntu remove xorg from the repositories completely? (That's interesting for me since I usually do a minimal ubuntu install and then add some exotic WM's I like).

If ubuntu will drop the support for xorg, is there any ubuntu based distro (like Mint or Lubuntu) which has official plans not to use xmir and to provide an own package of xorg instead?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the switch to Mir, please read the latest update of the [Ubuntu Graphics Stack Roadmap](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2013-June/037401.html). In short, Mir will be default compositor in 13.10, yet everything will **still use x11** through **xmir** an x.org will be available as fallback. In 14.04 x.org will be completely removed and everything should run through xmir. Starting from 14.10, Mir itself will be used by Unity, and xmir will only be there for backwards compatibility.

Debian, on which Ubuntu is based, will not switch to Wayland or Mir in the foreseeable future, so I expect x.org to be available in the Ubuntu repositories still for quite some time.

According to a [post in the phoronix forums](http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?82317-Canonical-Continues-Working-On-XMir-Performance&s=d9393a8655bde2b675a6c067fb544b5c&p=343192#post343192), **no other flavour** of Ubuntu will use Mir anytime soon and probably none of them ever will. Those that rely on toolkits ported to Wayland will maybe switch to Wayland.

(Sidenote: If you have time, read also [this](http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?82317-Canonical-Continues-Working-On-XMir-Performance/page7&s=d9393a8655bde2b675a6c067fb544b5c) *slightly* *cough* biased posting, it lists possible reasons.)

Answer (score 1):

Mythbuntu will test Mir during the 13.10 dev cycle. Will decide later what to do for 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've heard on most news sites and podcasts, is that Ubuntu is the only distribution to announce they will be using mir.  Kubuntu announced they will NOT adopt mir.  I don't know anyone else's official stances.

Answer (score 0):

Mir is developed by Canonical to be used with Unity. I don't think any distro that does not use Unity will use mir, there's no reason to do so. What you might see is a distro starting to use Unity or a Unity fork and replacing x by mir.

I don't think there's a way to tell when x will be completly dropped from the repositories for now, nor when it'll be replaced by mir as the official server.