# Ubuntu remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop

I want to remote control my Ubuntu from another Ubuntu. I need to have audio support and fast connection with the ability to issue shortcut keys, clipboard copy and use language switching.

I've heard about:

```
VNC
VNC + SSH Tunnelling
NX Server, free edition
FreeNX
NeatX
X2Go
X11 Forwarding over SSH
xrdp
x11rdp
LTSP
x11vnc
```

What I have tried so far:

```
VNC (SLOW)
VNC + SSH Tunnelling (SAME AS ABOVE)
NX Server, free edition 
FreeNX (LIMITATIONS -3 users - resolution...)
NeatX
X2Go
X11 Forwarding over SSH
xrdp (AUDIO SUPPORT - COMPLEX DEPLOYMENT)
x11rdp (AUDIO SUPPORT - COMPLEX DEPLOYMENT)
LTSP
x11vnc (AUDIO SUPPORT - COMPLEX DEPLOYMENT)
```

The solutions in [What free Remote Desktop (server) solutions are there?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4096/what-free-remote-desktop-server-solutions-are-there) do not answer my needs.

Note: Ubuntu may be going to [remove xorg implementation in the next release](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326809/which-ubuntu-derivatives-plan-to-support-xorg-in-the-future) (14.04 LTS) so we will not have the option of x server forwarding. I am developing Android applications and the Android emulator I use cannot run in xrdp. I can only start it with vnc. So I suffer from switching from xrdp to vnc all day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the best solution for remote controlling another desktop PC is [Team viewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/sr/index.aspx). It performs very fast, and it's cross-platform. It even works on android!

Comment: Teamviewer does not work in offline local network. Besides I can't allow teamviewer company to see my companies screens for free! thanks for your answer

Comment: You did not mention local network, although I think it works even on local networks. And, if you don't have internet connection, you don't have to worry about your screens being sent to teamviewer company.

Comment: There you go, it supports sessions over LAN [http://www.teamviewer.com/sr/help/40-Can-TeamViewer-be-used-within-a-local-network-LAN-only.aspx](http://www.teamviewer.com/sr/help/40-Can-TeamViewer-be-used-within-a-local-network-LAN-only.aspx)

Comment: I will try it honestly

Comment: Ok, if it works, please mark this question as answered.

Comment: You are awesome. How come I didn't pay attention to teamviewer LAN connections.

Comment: Thank you! I had the similar problem, so I found that solution.

Comment: can I know why the downvote after 2 months on inactivity?

Answer (score 0):

The *Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS* came pre-installed with **Remmina** that use the **RDP - Remote Desktop Protocol**, then it connect with *Microsoft Windows* OS too.

It setup is full feature and tweaks.

Beyond it have **SFTP**, **SSH** and **VNC** as alternative protocols.

Comment: I am talking on how to remote from windows to ubuntu

Comment: Sorry, but you said: "I want to remote control my ubuntu from another ubuntu".

So, in this case, the TeamViewer is a good paid solution, because it use the RDP protocol, not only the VNC protocol.

Comment: teamviewer is free for personal use. It doesn't use RDP! it has its own protocol